# How to remove list web part title link in sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Puting '#' in Title Url works in sharepoint on premise. But in online it redirects to /Pages/%23

Comment: How are you trying to put # in the Title Url

Comment: Edit web part > Advance > Title URL > Replaced the previous list url with #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try putting '@@@' in the Title Url field and then add below small script to your page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[href$='@@@']").prop('href','#');
});
```

Comment: this works.. but isn't there any sharepoint level setting for this? or any configuration setting

Comment: i'm glad it worked for you. As far as I know, there isn't any configuration setting to disable title link in list view webpart. Kindly accept this answer if it resolved your issue.

Comment: worked with this $("a[href$='@@@']").prop('href','javascript:'); thanx :)